# Deployment failing in websphere 8

Tags: parsing, deployment, websphere

I am trying to deploy an application in websphere 8 but i am getting below exception. I googled for it a lot but i did not find any relevant issues. Can anybody reply why the exception is occuring.

Exception:

```
[8/19/14 15:56:44:165 CDT] 00000021 wtp           W   Parse exception for [ public ID [ null ] and system ID [ null ] ] [ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid segment: /errorHandler ]
[8/19/14 15:56:44:179 CDT] 00000021 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application hmcwEAR failed.
[8/19/14 15:56:44:166 CDT] 00000021 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml
Stack trace of nested exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid segment: /errorHandler
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.validateURI(URI.java:1023)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createHierarchicalURI(URI.java:481)
    ........
```

Comment: Looks like problem in web.xml. Please attach it to the question.

Comment: The code i checked out is already in production and this is the first time i am trying to install the application by using Websphere 8. I hope there are no errors in web.xml.

Comment: Updating with Fix pack 7 for websphere 8 solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating with Fix pack 7 for websphere 8 solved this issue.